# Make dendextend assign colors to branches where I preset colors for leaves

Tags: r, plot, dendrogram, dendextend

I want to set the color of the  branches of my dendrogram, given manually-assigned groups of my leaves. So I know in advance I want to color e.g. leaves A-C in red and all branches which only lead to red leaves shall be colored red as well.

I can color branches of my dendrogram using the "dendextend" package.
However, I have no control about which color gets assigned to which cluster ID. `dendrextend` assigns the first color to the first cluster ID it finds, regardless of whether that's ID 1. However, I need ID 1 colored in color 1, etc., as I need a legend.

See this example. I want a dendrogram which colors the labels and branches `A`-`C` in red, `D`-`F` in blue and `G`-`I` in green.

```
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(dendextend))
library(dplyr)

set.seed(12346)
# Sample data: 
# ------------
# l = Leaf labels | g = assigned color of leaf | x = value for clustering
dat <- tibble(l = LETTERS[1:9],
              g = factor(rep(letters[1:3], each = 3)),
              x = round(runif(9,0,10)))

# color_branches() need integer cluster IDs
dat$gi <- dat$g %>% as.integer()

# Color IDs of each group
dat %>% distinct(g, gi)
## # A tibble: 3 x 2
##   g        gi
##   <fct> <int>
## 1 a         1
## 2 b         2
## 3 c         3
# ID 1 = red, ID 2 = blue, ID 3 = green
clucols <- c("red", "blue", "green")

# Clustering & Dendrogram
# -----------------------
dst <- dist(setNames(dat$x, dat$l))
den <- as.dendrogram(hclust(dst))
o <- order.dendrogram(den)

den <- den %>%
  color_branches(col = clucols, clusters = dat$gi[o]) 
# Transfer branch colors to labels
labels_colors(den) <- get_leaves_branches_col(den)

plot(den)

# Legend
dat %>% distinct(g, gi) %>%
{legend("topright", legend = .$g, col = clucols[.$gi], lty = 1)}
```

Result:

The leaves are not colored in my wanted order, but by cluster position on the plot from left to right

[image: Dendrogram with wrong coloring]

If you change the `set.seed(...)` line to `set.seed(12345)`, you see that the coloring seems correct. But this is because the clusters appear in correct order by chance, if seen from left to right:

[image: Dendrogram with correct coloring]

**How do I make `color_branches()` assign colors by cluster ID, not by which cluster comes first?**

## Other SO questions I tried

- [Dendextend: Regarding how to color a dendrogram’s labels according to defined groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45217384/dendextend-regarding-how-to-color-a-dendrogram-s-labels-according-to-defined-gr?rq=1): This question is related, but it only targets coloring labels.
- [Color dendrogram branches based on external labels uptowards the root until the label matches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36617699/color-dendrogram-branches-based-on-external-labels-uptowards-the-root-until-the?rq=1). An answer proposed `branches_attr_by_cluster`, which I translated into my example like this:

  ```
  den <- den %>%
    branches_attr_by_clusters(
      values = clucols[dat$gi[o]], 
      clusters = dat$gi[o], 
      attr = "col")
  ```

  However, alas the result was the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A workaround is to use the function `branches_attr_by_labels` to assign the color to branches for each group separately.

Replace this code in the question:

```
den <- den %>%
  color_branches(col = clucols, clusters = dat$gi[o])
```

with the code below.

You need to get a list which has each element for each group. Each element in turn contains the labels you want to color and the color itself. You get it for example like this:

```
library(purrr)
colmap <- dat %>% group_by(g) %>% summarise(l = list(l)) %>% transpose()
colmap

## [[1]]
## [[1]]$g
## [1] 1
## 
## [[1]]$l
## [1] "A" "B" "C"
## 
## 
## [[2]]
## [[2]]$g
## [1] 2
## 
## [[2]]$l
## [1] "D" "E" "F"
## 
## 
## [[3]]
## [[3]]$g
## [1] 3
## 
## [[3]]$l
## [1] "G" "H" "I"
```

Then, for each element, apply `branches_attr_by_labels`. As it takes a dendrogram and
some changing parameters and also returns a dendrogram, you can use `purrr::reduce` or `base::Reduce`:

```
den <- reduce(.x = colmap, .init = den, .f = function(d, m) 
  branches_attr_by_labels(d, m$l, clucols[m$g] ))
```

Alternatively, slightly longer:

```
for(e in colmap){
  den <- branches_attr_by_labels(den, e$l, clucols[e$g])
}
```

Result for `set.seed(123456)`. Compare to above picture:

[image: dendrogram with correct coloring]