# How do I add string variables to a dendrogram with labels coloured by factor level?

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, dendrogram, dendextend

One of the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27485549/how-to-colour-the-labels-of-a-dendrogram-by-an-additional-factor-variable-in-r) colour codes the labels of a dendogram for a subset of the iris dataset. What I would like to do is retain the string names for the labels so that they'd say setosa, virginica etc.along with their colours.

Here's the code

```
# install.packages("dendextend")
library(dendextend)

small_iris <- iris[c(1, 51, 101, 2, 52, 102), ]
dend <- as.dendrogram(hclust(dist(small_iris[,-5])))
# Like: 
# dend <- small_iris[,-5] %>% dist %>% hclust %>% as.dendrogram

# By default, the dend has no colors to the labels
labels_colors(dend)
par(mfrow = c(1,2))
plot(dend, main = "Original dend")

# let's add some color:
colors_to_use <- as.numeric(small_iris[,5])
colors_to_use
# But sort them based on their order in dend:
colors_to_use <- colors_to_use[order.dendrogram(dend)]
colors_to_use
# Now we can use them
labels_colors(dend) <- colors_to_use
# Now each state has a color
labels_colors(dend) 
plot(dend, main = "A color for every Species")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update the labels just before plotting. For example using `labels(dend) <- small_iris[,5][order.dendrogram(dend)]`

Full code and output:

```
# install.packages("dendextend")
library(dendextend)

small_iris <- iris[c(1, 51, 101, 2, 52, 102), ]
dend <- as.dendrogram(hclust(dist(small_iris[,-5])))
# Like: 
# dend <- small_iris[,-5] %>% dist %>% hclust %>% as.dendrogram

# By default, the dend has no colors to the labels
labels_colors(dend)
par(mfrow = c(1,2))
plot(dend, main = "Original dend")

# let's add some color:
colors_to_use <- as.numeric(small_iris[,5])
colors_to_use
# But sort them based on their order in dend:
colors_to_use <- colors_to_use[order.dendrogram(dend)]
colors_to_use
# Now we can use them
labels_colors(dend) <- colors_to_use
# Now each state has a color
labels_colors(dend) 

### UPDATE <--------------------------------
labels(dend) <- small_iris[,5][order.dendrogram(dend)]


plot(dend, main = "A color for every Species")
```

[image]